# How can i get array of object from this data for state and count in reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am having data  file in this array of objects form`[{name,state},{name,state},{name,state},{name,state},{name,state}]`
I need the state data and number of people belonging to same state, for that i need an array of objects having state and it's count like `[{state,count},{state, count},{state,count}]`
How can i get this reactjs?

Comment: can you share what you did so far? code snippet ? please follow stackoverflow question guidelines How to Ask? - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

This doesnt have anything to do with ReactJS, which is a library for rendering and managing UI.
In JS you can use a .reduce function to do that. I will produce and array with [{name: string, count: number}]:

```
const userArray = [{name: Riya, state: US}, {name: Chris, state: DE}]

const stateArray = userArray.reduce((newArray, currentElement) => {
  const stateExistsIndex = newArray.findIndex((state) => state.name === currentElement.state)
  if (stateExistsIndex !== -1) {
    const selectedState = newArray[stateExists] 
    newArray[stateExists] = { name: selectedState.name, count: selectedState.count++ }   
  } else {
    newArray.push({ name: currentElement.name, count: 1 })
  }

  return newArray
}, [])
```

This creates a new array. It loops through the old array and pushes an element to the new array if an state doesnt already exists. If it exists it increases its count by 1. You can of course also do it in a for-of loop which might be more easily understandable.

Comment: I am getting this error using the above code  "TypeError: newArray.findIndex is not a function"

Comment: sorry, its "indexOf" not findIndex and you have to check if its not -1 because thats the value it return when its not in the array

Comment: The currentElement is always undefined why is that?

Comment: The error is still occuring (TypeError): newArray.indexOf is not a function

Comment: Its the other way around, first parameter is the accumulator the second is the current value. Please check out the api for further info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

or just use a for-of loop:
```
let newArray = []

oldArray.forEach((element) => {
  if (newArray.findIndex(newElement => newElement.name === element.state) === -1)   {  // Push element to array  } else { increment count on new array element by 1 }
})
```

Comment: I have updated my answer for the correct syntax.

Comment: It's return the whole array with count always 1